# How can I get foreign exchange rates thru an API?

Tags: currency, forex, currency-exchange-rates

I need an API that provides latest currency exchange rates for my money transfer website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using [CurrencyFreaks API](https://currencyfreaks.com/). Its key features are:

- Reliable data as they source their data from various trusted Forex exchanges and
  Banks.
- You can get updates every 60 sec.
- You can change the ‘Base’    currency.
- It provides currency exchange rates for 179 currencies worldwide including currencies, metals, and cryptocurrencies.
- Supported codes for the endpoints are Shell, Node.js, Java, Python,
  PHP, Ruby, JS, C#, Go, C, Swift.

Here is the latest exchange rates endpoint:

```
$ curl 'https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY'
```

The JSON response will be as follows:

```
{
    "date": "2020-07-02 10:39:00+00",
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "FJD": 2.1692,
        "MXN": 22.602,
        "STD": 22000.6197,
        "SCR": 17.6,
        "LVL": 0.6563,
        "CDF": 1907.87,
        "BBD": 2.0,
        "GTQ": 7.7,
        "CLP": 808.6,
        "UGX": 3721.0,
        "HNL": 24.7553,
        "ZAR": 16.9326,
        "TND": 2.8445,
        "CUC": 1.0,
        "SLL": 9778.35,
        "BSD": 1.0,
      [...]
    } }
```

You can also get live currency exchange rates from here: https://currencyfreaks.com/exchange-rates

Hope it will help you.